# JS onMouseDown and onMouseUp events Safari iPhone: can not make them working

Tags: javascript, iphone, events, mouse

I'm using iPhone with iOS 10.3.2(14F89) and its correspondent Safari.

My goal is: when the user starts tapping (presses) an image I need to receive "onMouseDown" event and when he/she finishes tapping the image I need to receive "onMouseUp" (released) event.

After searching and making lots of tests with following code:

```
<style>
   body { -webkit-touch-callout: unset !important; }
   img  { -webkit-user-select: none !important; } 
</style>

<body>
   <img src="an_image.png" onMouseDown="onPressed()" onMouseUp="onReleased()">
</body>

<script>
    function onPressed()
    {
        console.log( "pressed" );
    }

    function onReleased()
    {
        console.log( "released" );
    }
</script>
```

But the contextual menu always appear or at least the magnifier.
I tried also other "-webkit" directives with no luck.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

the onMouseDown and onMouseUp are usually mouse events and you would always want to use touch events to handle touch events

Comment: Hi Ashwin. Thanks a million for your fast and precise answer.

Clearly I have to deal with these events, but I'm having another problem that is not solved when using these events: the default behaviour. Context menu and magnifier are shown in Safari after few seconds pressing an image.

Would you be so kind to let me know how to solve it (if you know)?
Thanks again.

Comment: you could mark it as the correct answer to show appreciation :) @peyrona

Comment: Hello again Ashwin.
I can no delete my comment to your answer but I have to publicly apologize: your answer is the correct solution.
Thank you very much and sorry for forgetting to mark your answer previously.

Comment: no but you said about some native issue in safari.. do you want to disable that feature or are you looking to enable that feature?